# website connection reset

Tags: domain-name-system

I have two domain name with one site all hosted in local isp's server.http://www.example.net,http://www.example.com.Some customer of mine always complain that they cannot access my site(first) with status **connection reset**,and all get successful ping through. I have to let customers switch to the second domain.
could you please tell me what is the probably reason and how to solve it,Thanks.and forgive my poor English.

Comment: Please provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a DNS issue.  Since they can ping it successfully, and since it's a connection reset issue, it's likely something on the web server.

Are both of your domain names pointing to the same site?  I would start with the web server and see what differences you can find there.

The more information you can provide here the better.

Comment: thanks a lot,that's server fault :),I have changed to another server and problem got solved.My domain names not point to the same site .
thanks a lot!

Comment: Great, glad you got it solved.